# 4-gon with two opposite sides congruent and two opposite angles congruent: necessarily a parallelogram?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

My kid's geometry classmate tried to use the following "theorem" in a proof:

> If a quadrilateral has a pair of opposite sides congruent and a pair of opposite angles congruent, it's a parallelogram.

The teacher (correctly) didn't allow this, as they hadn't proven the "theorem" in class. The teacher, moreover, conjectured but could not prove that the "theorem" was in fact *false*. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is in fact false; here's a family of counterexamples:

Consider isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$ with $\overline{AB}\Vert\overline{CD}$ and $AD=BC$. Cut it into two triangles along diagonal $\overline{AC}$ and glue them together by identifying $\overline{AD}$ to $\overline{BC}$, $A$ to $B$, $D$ to $C$. The resulting quadrilateral has a pair of opposite sides congruent because they were the diagonal $\overline{AC}$ of the trapezoid, and a pair of opposite angles congruent because they were corresponding angles $(\angle BAC,\angle ACD)$ across a transversal of parallel lines.

Moreover, *every* quadrilateral (without intersecting sides) that's not a parallelogram but has a pair of opposite sides congruent and a pair of opposite angles congruent can be constructed using that method. Indeed, consider such a quadrilateral $MNOP$, WLOG $MN=OP$ and $\angle N\cong\angle P$. Cut it along $\overline{MO}$ and glue the resulting triangles by identifying $\overline{MN}$ to $\overline{PO}$, $M$ to $P$, $N$ to $O$. The resulting quadrilateral has two congruent sides from $\overline{MO}$ and the other two sides are parallel because corresponding angles $(\angle N,\angle P)$ across the transversal are congruent. Moreover, it's not a parallelogram: if it were, the other pair of opposite sides would be congruent, $NO=MP$, so the original $MNOP$ would be a parallelogram also. Thus it's an isosceles trapezoid, as required.